# Excel VBA - Entering Filter into Pivot Table returning Object Required

Tags: vba, excel

I have some VBA code which is set up to look up a dynamic (changing) table of data, the code then changes the range to fit into pivot tables, and refreshes the pivot tables based on the new range.

The code works until it reaches the part where it needs to apply a filter.  I have a date value which I have declared under a String called PivotFilter, when the code goes to apply the filter, i get a Run Time error 1004 - Application defined or Object defined error

I have been trying to figure this out for the last two hours, and cannot seem to fix it, I have tried to change the string to a range, this also didn't work.  Any suggestions?

*EDIT*
Fixed the typo in the erroneous section, and i'm still getting application defined or object defined error

```
Sub PortfolioDataLoad()

Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim ws1, ws2, ws3, ws4, ws5 As Worksheet
Dim r1, r2, r3 As Range
Dim StartPoint, DataRange As Range
Dim PivotName, Pivotname2, Pivotname3, Pivotname4 As String
Dim Datefrom, Dateto As Range
Dim PivotFilter As String


PivotFilter = Worksheets("Configuration").Range("B1")

PivotName = "PivotTable3"
Pivotname2 = "PivotTable4"
Pivotname3 = "PivotTable5"
Pivotname4 = "PivotTable1"

Application.StatusBar = "Transforming data into report graphs..."

'Set Variables Here

Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("Control Sheet")
Set ws2 = wb1.Sheets("Program Data")
Set ws3 = wb1.Sheets("Configuration")
Set ws4 = wb1.Sheets("Overview")


If ws1.Visible = False Then
   ws1.Visible = True
End If

'Dynamically Retrieve Data from Program Data
Set StartPoint = ws2.Range("A1")
Set DataRange = ws2.Range(StartPoint, StartPoint.SpecialCells(xlLastCell))
NewRange = ws2.Name & "!" & _
       DataRange.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)

If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(DataRange.Rows(1)) > 0 Then
    MsgBox "One of your data columns in the 'Program Data' tab has a blank heading." & vbNewLine _
      & "Please fix and re-run!.", vbCritical, "Column Heading Missing!"
    Exit Sub
 End If

'Change Pivot Range to Cache set above
ws3.PivotTables(PivotName).ChangePivotCache _
    ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
    SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
    SourceData:=NewRange)

ws3.PivotTables(Pivotname2).ChangePivotCache _
    ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
    SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
    SourceData:=NewRange)

ws3.PivotTables(Pivotname3).ChangePivotCache _
    ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
    SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
    SourceData:=NewRange)

ws3.PivotTables(Pivotname4).ChangePivotCache _
    ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
    SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
    SourceData:=NewRange)


'Refresh Tables
ws3.PivotTables(PivotName).RefreshTable
ws3.PivotTables(Pivotname2).RefreshTable
ws3.PivotTables(Pivotname3).RefreshTable
ws3.PivotTables(Pivotname4).RefreshTable


'Set Date in Pivot Table Filter - Results in Run-time error '424': Object Required

ws3.PivotTables(PivotName).PivotFields("Planning Month").PivotFilters.Add _
Type:=xlBeforeOrEqualTo, Value1:=PivotFilter

ws3.PivotTables(Pivotname2).PivotFields("Planning Month").PivotFilters.Add _
Type:=xlBeforeOrEqualTo, Value1:=PivotFilter

ws3.PivotTables(Pivotname4).PivotFields("Planning Month").PivotFilters.Add _
Type:=xlBeforeOrEqualTo, Value1:=PivotFilter

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've got a typo where `w3` should be `ws3`.  I believe the lines

```vb
w3.PivotTables(PivotName).PivotFields("Planning Month").PivotFilters.Add _
Type:=xlBeforeOrEqualTo, Value1:=PivotFilter

w3.PivotTables(Pivotname2).PivotFields("Planning Month").PivotFilters.Add _
Type:=xlBeforeOrEqualTo, Value1:=PivotFilter

w3.PivotTables(Pivotname4).PivotFields("Planning Month").PivotFilters.Add _
Type:=xlBeforeOrEqualTo, Value1:=PivotFilter
```

should be

```vb
ws3.PivotTables(PivotName).PivotFields("Planning Month").PivotFilters.Add _
Type:=xlBeforeOrEqualTo, Value1:=PivotFilter

ws3.PivotTables(Pivotname2).PivotFields("Planning Month").PivotFilters.Add _
Type:=xlBeforeOrEqualTo, Value1:=PivotFilter

ws3.PivotTables(Pivotname4).PivotFields("Planning Month").PivotFilters.Add _
Type:=xlBeforeOrEqualTo, Value1:=PivotFilter
```

Also, note that `NewRange` wasn't defined.

Using `Option Explicit` can help find these.  You can read more about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg278855(v=office.14).aspx).

Be aware that when you define multiple items on a single line, only the last variable is actually defined with the type specified.  For example:

```
Dim PivotName, Pivotname2, Pivotname3, Pivotname4 As String
```

results in variable `Pivotname4` being created as `String` but variables `PivotName`, `Pivotname2` and `Pivotname3` created as `Variant`.

You're assigning `String` values to `PivotName`, `Pivotname2` and `Pivotname3` so if you look at the item type while debugging, you'll see they are `Variant/String`.  It seems that it should be okay, but it could be an issue.

You could try altering your `Dim` statments to explicitly set the variable type to `String` as I think you intended.  For example:

```vb
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim ws3 As Worksheet
Dim ws4 As Worksheet
Dim ws5 As Worksheet
Dim r1 As Range
Dim r2 As Range
Dim r3 As Range
Dim StartPoint As Range
Dim DataRange As Range
Dim PivotName As String
Dim Pivotname2 As String
Dim Pivotname3 As String
Dim Pivotname4 As String
Dim Datefrom As Range
Dim Dateto As Range
Dim PivotFilter As String
Dim NewRange As Range
```

One more thing: Does the `PivotField` named "Planning Month" exist in the PivotTables?  You may need to add it if it doesn't exist before you can apply the filter to it.

Comment: Apologies, I just corrected that typo but i'm still getting application defined or object defined error

Comment: Thank you for these, I have changed the declarations to be more explicit like you have shown above, there is a planning month value in the filter of my pivot tables but it is still showing the same error.

Could it be that the code is referencing a cell value with a specific date format of dd/mm/yy? (Australian date system)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing anything defined for "w3".  You have "ws3" and others, but no "w3".  Is that it?

edit: 
If you are still getting the error, it's possible there is a problem with "Planning Month"

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to all for your help in this, the problem appears to be that the date value is not being recognized as an object, therefore I had to do this another way. I created a loop to check the values in the data table against the date in the 'control sheet'.  If they were lesser than the date or equal to it, then the value would be 'Include', else it would be 'Dont include'.  The filter was then set to 'Include'.  Code below

```
Private Sub WorkSheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim ws3 As Worksheet
Dim ws4 As Worksheet
Dim r1 As Range
Dim r2 As Range
Dim r3 As Range
Dim StartPoint As Range
Dim DataRange As Range
Dim NewRange As String
Dim PivotName As String
Dim Pivotname2 As String
Dim Pivotname3 As String
Dim Pivotname4 As String
Dim Datefrom As Range
Dim Dateto As Range
Dim PivotFilter As String

PivotFilter = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Overview").Range("Z2")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
PivotName = "PivotTable3"
Pivotname2 = "PivotTable4"
Pivotname3 = "PivotTable5"
Pivotname4 = "PivotTable1"

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("Z2:Z2")) Is Nothing Then
  If TargetVal <> Target Then
Application.StatusBar = "Transforming data into report graphs..."

'Set Variables Here

Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("Control Sheet")
Set ws2 = wb1.Sheets("Program Data")
Set ws3 = wb1.Sheets("Configuration")
Set ws4 = wb1.Sheets("Overview")


If ws1.Visible = False Then
   ws1.Visible = True
End If

If ws2.Visible = False Then
   ws2.Visible = True
End If

'Dynamically Retrieve Data from Program Data

ws2.Select
ws2.Range("H2").Select
  Do Until IsEmpty(Selection)
  If ActiveCell.Value <= PivotFilter Then
     ActiveCell.Offset(0, 28).Value = "Include"
     Else
     ActiveCell.Offset(0, 28).Value = "Dont Include"
  End If
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop

Set StartPoint = ws2.Range("A1")
Set DataRange = ws2.Range(StartPoint, StartPoint.SpecialCells(xlLastCell))
NewRange = ws2.Name & "!" & _
       DataRange.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)

If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(DataRange.Rows(1)) > 0 Then
    MsgBox "One of your data columns in the 'Program Data' tab has a blank heading." & vbNewLine _
    & "Please fix and re-run!.", vbCritical, "Column Heading Missing!"
    Exit Sub
End If


ws3.PivotTables(PivotName).ChangePivotCache _
    ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
    SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
    SourceData:=NewRange)

ws3.PivotTables(Pivotname2).ChangePivotCache _
    ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
    SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
    SourceData:=NewRange)

ws3.PivotTables(Pivotname3).ChangePivotCache _
    ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
    SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
    SourceData:=NewRange)

ws3.PivotTables(Pivotname4).ChangePivotCache _
    ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
    SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
    SourceData:=NewRange)



ws3.PivotTables(PivotName).RefreshTable
ws3.PivotTables(Pivotname2).RefreshTable
ws3.PivotTables(Pivotname3).RefreshTable
ws3.PivotTables(Pivotname4).RefreshTable

ws3.PivotTables(PivotName).PivotFields("Planning Period"). _
CurrentPage = "Include"

ws3.PivotTables(Pivotname4).PivotFields("Planning Period"). _
CurrentPage = "Include"

ws3.PivotTables(Pivotname2).PivotFields("Planning Period"). _
CurrentPage = "Include"

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Overview").Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End If
Exit Sub
```